# Как наследовать тип от JSX.IntrinsicElements.mesh?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx, typescript-типы

Есть кастомный реакт тег, созданный другой библиотекой, я хочу сделать на него компонент враппер, но в пропсах этого враппера принимать еще один дополнительный проп, а остальное элементу передавать..

```
interface MeshProps extends ????? {
  value: number
}


const Mesh: FC<MeshProps> = ({ value, ...props }) => {
    return <mesh {...props} />
}
```

когда я пишу вот так, то получаю ошибку:

```
interface MeshProps extends JSX.IntrinsicElements.mesh {
  value: number
}
```

`TS2694: Namespace 'global.JSX' has no exported member 'IntrinsicElements'.`

Как подцепить определение `JSX.IntrinsicElements.mesh` и наследовать от него?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ни я ни `IntrinsicElements` не знаем что такое `mesh`, но вот пример на `div`:

```
// interface QwaProps extends JSX.IntrinsicElements['div'] {} // An interface can only extend an identifier/qualified-name with optional type arguments.(2499)

type $QwaProps = JSX.IntrinsicElements['div'] & {
    qwa: any
}

const qq: $QwaProps = null as any
qq.qwa
```

[песочница](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wFgAoCgeirmADsYkpN0k4BZJAZwAsAFHGG5wkADyb0AJiIBSAZQAaAOgCSjKA27A0AUQA2SEEkbdlxvnADe1WnHtwAbin0BXJAC449VyABGzLZwAL4UQQxMLGxwAIoA7iiCEMKiEiYycAoq6jCa9Np6hsamANr4UsCO%20AC61sFwNHAAgvR0jMysaOxoKK0Q9PoAnqmSUnC9dFImMMCYwMxUAI6uLrPzUgC09CjGcHHAMLxwyTP9LnAwg2DsKFAA5r7TZgAUAEwALACcnwCUYeSXa5wAAk8USQhEAF5Mko1BotDoDEYnmUKlVagAyawUBxwRYJLy9QYUUKUchofrceCLRZeUEJJIpaE%20fT6cYiIkUGnKfEof5AA)

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Огромнейшее!